# Why my youtube in webview play only sound?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

My code runs and I can hear the sound.  However, the video is just a black screen. Here is my code:

```
    myWebView = (WebView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYkLG0KoUfM");
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If the mobile device doesn't have flash configured then it may not be able to play the video and you will get a blank screen.

Make sure that your flash player is configured correctly on the device and that the device does indeed have flash player support on it.

Comment: My device plays the videos properly when using Youtube App or any browsers but not in my app. :(

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively try youtubes embed url format which has html5 fallback.

```
myWebView = (WebView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
myWebView.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/pYkLG0KoUfM");
```

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

If you use the new embed code style, your viewers will be able to view your embedded video in one of our Flash or HTML5 players, depending on their viewing environment and preferences. Environments that support the HTML5 video player are listed here on our HTML5 settings page. In instances where HTML5 isn't supported (e.g. our HTML5 player can't play videos with ads), we use Flash.

An additional benefit of the new embed style is that it will eventually allow embeds to work on mobile devices, which typically use a built-in player instead of Flash or HTML5.

Before we make this new embed code the standard for our general users, we wanted to give our developer community a preview. While there may be some limitations, please try it out and let us know how it went.

Comment: I was unaware of this.  Do you have any information on how it chooses what the player will be?  Some more documentation would be useful to app developers.